# Load kotlin resource from outside a class

Tags: kotlin

I have a couple of top level functions in my Kotlin code:

```
fun getSomeText(path: String): String? {
    // return contents of the path relative to src/main/resources/some_dir
}
```

Where this function simply returns the content of the file in `src/main/resources/some_dir/path`. I don't have a class to access `::class.java.getResource` from. I've seen people using `{}::class.java.getResource`, but this creates a new object whenever a resource is accessed. Is there a built-in way to access a resource from a static context in kotlin?

Comment: note that `Something::class.java.getResource` does not (if the path doesn't start with `/`) give you the resource relative to the classpath root (`src/main/resources`) but relative to the class. Which do you want?

Comment: @dan1st I want to retrieve the file at `src/main/resources/my_custom_dir/path`. `my_custom_dir` is some constant directory and `path` is relative to `my_custom_dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to create an anomymous class, and (as I understand from your comment) the given path should always be relative to a given path "/my_custom_dir", you can for instance use `Any`'s class's class to get the resource from that class:

```kotlin
fun getSomeText(path: String): String? =
    Any::class::class.java.getResource("/my_custom_dir/$path").readText()
```

As far as I can tell, it does not work with just `Any::class`, but with `Any::class::class`.

Further, please note that the leading slash in the path makes sure that you do look for a path relative to your classpath's root and not relative to the given class's location.

---

If you can be sure that the function is called from inside a class, an alternative would be to use the class of the caller like this:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> T.getSomeText(path: String): String? =
    this::class.java.getResource("/my_custom_dir/$path").readText()
```

From inside any class this function can just be called like `getSomeText(...)` without the need to explicitly specify the receiver. When you take away the `/my_custom_dir/` part of the path, this function has the advantage that you can also use it to load some resource relative to the calling class.